# Va a encantarle a alguien - encantarle or lo?

Tags: traducción, gramática, pronombres

En una tarea para mi clase de español, usé las oraciones siguientes:

> Le compré un collar a mi madre. ¡Va a encantarle!

Las usé para decir

> I bought my mother a necklace. She's going to love it!

Mi profesora me dijo que debo decir "va a encantar**lo**" en lugar de "encantar**le**"

Creo que lo correcto es "le" porque refiere al complemento indirecto, "mi madre".

¿Cuál es correcta?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Exactamente. En la frase

> "*Va a encantarle*"

Le es el complemento indirecto ("*a mi madre*")
y *el collar* es el sujeto de la frase.
Si se tratase de dos collares, dirías:

> "*Le compré dos collares a mi madre. **¡Van** a encantar**le**!*"

También sería correcto decir:

> "*Le compré dos collares a mi madre. ¡Le van a encantar!*"

Answer (score 1):

Josh!

When «encantar» refers to putting someone under a spell,” it’s transitive. It takes *complemento direct*o:

> «El hechizo mágico del collar va a encantar a mi madre».
>
> «El hechizo mágico del collar va a encantar**la**».

When it refers to liking something/someone very much, it’s intransitive. It takes *complemento indirecto*:

> «El collar le va a encantar a mi madre».
>
> «El collar va a encantar**le**».